# Completely remove thousands of .pdf files from previous revisons of git?

Tags: git

Previously, I deleted thousands of .pdf files from a git repo. But the issue is that, even if I removed these files, they are still present in previous revisions so that I can still get them back by accessing the history. And now I get very large pack files which is very frustrating.

Now I want to completely remove all these .pdf files from all the revisons of git and I don't want to get them back ever and ever to reduce the size of my repo. How can I do that? All the .pdf files were removed in a commit.

I searched on Google and found `git filter-branch` may solve my problem. But all the solutions I found is to find **a very big file** in the git revisons and completely delete it from the repo. What I want is to completely remove thousands of .pdf files that took very disk space.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thx.

Comment: Whether removing one big file, many big files, many small files, etc., the principle is the same.  The filter-branch command extracts existing commits, applies your filters, and makes new commits out of the result, then adjusts branch labels (and tags if you use a tag filter) to point to the new commits instead of the old ones.  The tricky part is writing the filter(s): it's easier if the files are all in one known place (which if there's just one big file, that's really easy).

Comment: @torek Unfortunately, the files are distributed in many directories. But I am wondering if I can use regular expression to mathch pdf files in the `git filter-branch` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per comments, expanded into an answer...

There are two easy (well, "not terribly hard") ways to deal with that:

1. Use `--tree-filter` (very slow) with this filter:

   ```
   git filter-branch ... \
       --tree-filter "find . -name '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 rm" \
       ...
   ```
2. Use `--index-filter` (much faster):

   ```
   git filter-branch ... \
       --index-filter "git ls-files -z -- '*.pdf' | xargs -0 git rm --cached" \
       ...
   ```

In either case, be sure to include `--tag-name-filter cat` if you want tags to move to the copied commits (and read the rest of the documentation on using `filter-branch`).

This assumes you want to get rid of *all* files whose names match `*.pdf`.  If you need to be more selective, note that `filter-branch` just runs the filter with `eval $filter`: there is nothing that says that the `...` part cannot be, or include, a path to a shell script, where you can write complex tests without having to fit them into one big `eval`-able string.

Comment: at least in `zsh` you can even do it simpler with via recursive matching:
`git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch repo/**/*.pdf'`

Comment: @Seriously: That's probably going to use Git's internal pathspec expansion. Each filter is `eval`-ed by the shell running the filter-branch script, which is `/bin/sh`, regardless of which shell you use. The filter runs with `$PWD` in the temporary directory that filter-branch sets up, which in this case is mostly or wholly empty. The `git ls-files` method is more flexible for more complex cases, though, so better as an illustration at least.